# How to sum results from 2 diffrent queries in PostgresQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 different but similar queries like

```
select id, name, count(*) from tb_2020_01 inner join … inner join tb2_2020_01 … inner join group by count(*) … (there is no order)

id  name  count
1   One   111
2   Two   222
5   Five  555
```

and then

```
select id, name, count(*) from tb_2020_02 inner join … inner join tb2_2020_02 … inner join group by count(*) … (there is no order)

id name  count
1  One   100
3  Three 333
```

I want to sum results from both of these queries like

```
id name  count
1  One   211
2  Two   222
3  Three 333
5  Five  555
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: UNION ALL and aggregate one more time.

Comment: I'd rather ask myself if separate tables for each month is a good idea. Can't you store all data in one table instead?

Comment: @jarlh I know it is a very bad idea but unfortunately I have no authority on the database

Answer (score 1):

The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

- Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns
- The columns must also have similar data types
- The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

See **SQL UNION** on :  [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
select id, name, count(*) from tb_2020_01
UNION ALL
select id, name, count(*) from tb_2020_02
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select x."id", x."name", sum(x."count") from
(

select id, name, count(*) from tb_2020_01 inner join … inner join tb2_2020_01 … inner join group by count(*) … (there is no order)

UNION ALL

select id, name, count(*) from tb_2020_02 inner join … inner join tb2_2020_02 … inner join group by count(*) … (there is no order)

) x group by x."id", x."name"
```